# Get the current position or the value of the slider

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++

I am using Devcomponents slider component in my application.What I require is to get the value of the current position when the slider is adgested.
I know facts about setting the maximum,minimum and the step properties of the slider.
I wanted to programatically control the slider within a slider1_ValueChanged() event.
Note: For any one to get idea about slider control on Devcomponents refer the follwing [link](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a `Value` property on the slider you can use?

Comment: yes bro i can find a value property with slider, I was completely out of mind thank you for the support ill try this one to see whether this works.